# Click event on DirectionsRenderer or any other alternate

Tags: google-maps

I have requirement, I need to create draggable route and at some point I want to display coordinate on click over draggable route.

I am implementing functionality like this,

```
directionsDisplay.addListener('click', function(event) {
            // Some opeation.
});
```

but click event does not work on draggable DirectionsRenderer. 
I want to implement some operation on click event over map cursor showing in below picture.

[image]

Comment: what do you want to show??.

Comment: @Deep3015 I want to get coordinate at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Using code from [directions-draggable](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-draggable), you can get the coordinate of the changed direction route as

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/56k42dz8/)

```
function computeTotalDistance(result) {
  var total = 0;
  var myroute = result.routes[0];
  for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
    //console.log(myroute.legs[i])
    console.log('Start Loc: ' + myroute.legs[i].start_location + 'Start Location: ' + myroute.legs[i].start_address);
    console.log('End Loc:' + myroute.legs[i].end_location + 'End Location: ' + myroute.legs[i].end_address);
    total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
  }
  total = total / 1000;
  document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
}
```

Comment: It will return coordinate when we drag route. In case I am not dragging route, I am just clicking on route to print coordinate. As I shown in image

Comment: looking for this scenario. wait

Comment: i think you have to find from `console.log(myroute.legs[i].steps)`  as one of the point exist in that object

Comment: I am able to get coordinate on direction_change but issue is this I am not able to get point on click. DirectionsRenderer not supporting click event.